# php replacing query duplicates for empty strings

Tags: php, sql, duplicates

i have the following script to retrieve sql data:

```
  // Present data if avail
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // Query output in tabels
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo '<tr> <td class="tg">' .$row["id"]. '</td>' . "\n";
       echo '<td class="tg">' .$row["fname"]. '</td>' . "\n";
       echo '<td class="tg">' .$row["lname"]. '</td>' . "\n";
       echo '<td class="tg">' .$row["make"].  '</td></tr>' . "\n";      

   }
   // if no records
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
```

How can i replace duplicates in the row 'fname' for empty strings? (records are being ordered by fname)

Comment: Can you clear up what exactly you're asking for? (Give Sample Data)

Are you attempting to find only unique rows? you should do that in your SQL query. If you have data where you're trying to remove duplicate rows you can do that in PHP, but it's unclear what you're asking for exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you showed us doesn't retrieve SQL data - it just displays it. If you managed to write the code above then this should be obvious:

```
$prevname='';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo '<tr> <td class="tg">' .$row["id"]. '</td>' . "\n";
   echo '<td class="tg">' 
      . ( $row["fname"] == $prevname ? '' : $row["fname"])
      . '</td>' . "\n";
   echo '<td class="tg">' .$row["lname"]. '</td>' . "\n";
   echo '<td class="tg">' .$row["make"].  '</td></tr>' . "\n";      
   $prevname=$r["fname"];
}
```

Comment: although it seems obvious to an average coder it's not for a beginner. thanks a million.